# Facebook share displays specialchars (æøå) as �

Tags: html, facebook, character-encoding

I use the this url:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=+100&p%5Btitle%5D=SiTs+helsetilbud&p%5Burl%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sit.no%2Fhelse&p%5Bsummary%5D=SiT+tilbyr+tjenester+som+kan+hjelpe+studenter+p%E5+veien+mot+god+helse.+Bredden+i+v%E5rt+helsetilbud+er+stor%2C+og+alle+tjenestene+er+tilpasset+studentenes+behov.+SiT+kan+hjelpe+deg%21&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fsithelse.unco.no%2Ffileshare%2Ffilarkivroot%2Fhelse%2FFacebookdeling%2FAngst.png

To share on facebook. It works well in firefox but renders wrong in IE. Norwegian characters  æ ø å as �.

I've tried to replace it with å and iso %e5

Any suggestions?

Comment: For the record, it renders those characters as � in Chrome, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the value returned by JavaScript's [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for these characters. For instance:

```
> encodeURIComponent('å')
"%C3%A5"
```

So, just to fix that one character in the link, use `%C3%A5` (**not** `%E5` or `å`):

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=+100&p%5Btitle%5D=SiTs+helsetilbud&p%5Burl%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sit.no%2Fhelse&p%5Bsummary%5D=SiT+tilbyr+tjenester+som+kan+hjelpe+studenter+p%C3%A5+veien+mot+god+helse.+Bredden+i+v%C3%A5rt+helsetilbud+er+stor%2C+og+alle+tjenestene+er+tilpasset+studentenes+behov.+SiT+kan+hjelpe+deg%21&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fsithelse.unco.no%2Ffileshare%2Ffilarkivroot%2Fhelse%2FFacebookdeling%2FAngst.png